# Observium default snmp v3 communities for auto discovery

Tags: monitoring, snmp, autodiscovery, observium

From the documentation I found it's possible to add multiple snmp v1 & v2 communities via the community array in `config.php` but I have a larger network with v3 only;

Is there a way to define snmp v3 values which are used to query new devices?
In the global settings via the GUI it's only possible to set the default version to v3 but not possible to enter values;

I do not want to add every v3 device manually - would like to use the subnet auto discovery but don't know how and where to enter the v3 parameters or is this only possible with v1 & v2 ?

Comment: Try set `$config['snmp']['version'] = "v3";` and `$config['autodiscovery']['ip_nets']` values. For v3 values see http://www.observium.org/docs/config_options/#snmp-settings you can add a list of parameters.

Comment: I've have the v3 credentials in config.php and i've configured auto-discovery but it looks like it's not performing auto-discovery;
Also added an entry in the hosts file for the ip seen as BGP peer from an device already in the db where i also have the 'Require valid hostname' option disabled;